# In a dotnet 5 web api project, how do I get the instance of a singleton service in a test method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm integration testing my asp.net 5 web apis. In my test methods I want to get a reference to the instance a of faked service so I can customise the service's behaviour for my tests.

In the app, the service is scoped as singleton.

```
//in ConfigureServices in Startup.cs    
services.AddSingleton<IYbNewProjectsService, YbNewProjectsService>();
```

In my test project, I set up my client and server in my TestFixture class, and save a reference to the ServiceProvider, returned to me by the services.BuildServiceProvider() call...

```
private void SetupClient()
{
    Client = Factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.Remove<IYbNewProjectsService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IYbNewProjectsService, FakeYbNewProjetsService>();
        });

        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        });
    })
    .CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false
    });
}
```

I know it's working, because in my tests, when I do...

```
// ServiceProvider is inherited from TestFixture, so it's the same as above.
var fakeYbService = (FakeYbNewProjectsService)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IYbNewProjectsService));
fakeYbService.InjectedResponse = @"[{{""idProjet"":1883557,""dateDApplication"":...
var response = await Client.GetAsync("/api/yb-new-projects");
```

...I get my faked service. Trouble is, when I call `Client.GetAsync()`, the TestServer is using a clean instance of the same faked service, without my `InjectedResponse`. This is meant to be a singleton, so why are there two of them?

Comment: What is `ServiceProvider`? If it inherits from your test fixture which in turn inherits from the test factory, it's *another* test factory with its own DI container and services. In `SetupClient` the test factory isn't stored anywhere so it can't be used except through the client.

Comment: Sorry I didn't show you that. Factory is saved, as an instance property of TestFixture. I have also tried `Factory.Services.GetService()`, but it gets me a fresh copy of _the real service_, not the fake.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to setup a `ServiceProvider` yourself, it's available on the `Factory`:

```cs
// Use this:
Factory.Services.GetService(typeof(IYbNewProjectsService));

// Instead of:
ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IYbNewProjectsService));
```

It works correctly for me with this setup (.NET 5 Razor pages app + .NET 5 XUnit test project):

```cs
// In app Startup.ConfigureServices:
services.AddSingleton<ITestService, TestService>();

// Test
[Fact]
public async Task Test1()
{
    var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>()
        .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<ITestService, FakeTestService>();
            });
        });

    var svc = factory.Services.GetService<ITestService>();
    svc.Do();

    var client = factory.CreateDefaultClient();

    await client.GetAsync("http://localhost");
}
```

The endpoint it calls also gets the `ITestService` and calls the method.
In both cases I hit the breakpoint in the `FakeTestService`.

One thing you could check is that does the `Startup.ConfigureServices` run before the `ConfigureTestServices`?
In my case it does which allows us to overwrite the service.
If they were to run in the other order, your test service would get overwritten.
In this case you would need to use `TryAddSingleton` instead in your Startup class.

Comment: I tried that Friday. I tried it again now. I have breakpoints everywhere. When I do as you suggest, I hit 1) the real registration 2) the remove-and-add-fake, very good 3) GetService() in my test 4) the real registration _again_, oh no 5) Exception in the test because I can't cast to fake, because it isnt the fake.

Comment: Just tried Factory.Server.Services.GetService(), and it's the same. I get a new copy of the real service.

Comment: That's odd :\ I'll have to test this more..

Comment: Added an example of what worked for me.

Comment: thanks for your dedication. 1 difference is that I never new my WebApplicationFactory. I inherit IClassFixture, then get it in the constructor. I will have a look tomorrow.